# No @Autowired for Mapsruct class as well as for @Service class

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, autowired, mapstruct

I am trying to use MapStruct for DTO to Entity(Product) mapping and vice versa by referring to this [blog](https://hellokoding.com/mapping-jpa-hibernate-entity-and-dto-with-mapstruct/).

```
├── product
   ├── Product.java
   ├── ProductAPI.java
   ├── ProductDTO.java
   ├── ProductMapper.java
   ├── ProductRespository.java
   └── ProductService.java
```

In the controller I cannot see `@Autowired` for `productService`(@Service) and `productMapper`(@Mapper).

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;


import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/products")
public class ProductAPI {
    private final ProductService productService;
    private final ProductMapper productMapper;

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<List<ProductDTO>> findAll() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(productMapper.toProductDTOs(productService.findAll()));
    }

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<ProductDTO> create(@RequestBody ProductDTO productDTO) {
        productService.save(productMapper.toProduct(productDTO));

        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(productDTO);
    }
}
```

I would like to know why there would be not Dependency Injection for MapStruct class (i.e. `prodcutMapper`).

Is it because Mapstruct framework is responsible for calling itself at controller layer? Does the same go for `@Service` service layer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring allows you to omit the @Autowired annotation if the Bean has one constructor (provided by the @RequiredArgsConstructor in your case).

So in short, the dependency injection is happening because the @Autowired effect is happening and the annotation itself is omitted in this case.

Check the docs [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.3.RELEASE/reference/html/using-boot-spring-beans-and-dependency-injection.html).

Answer (score 0):

This is **WRONG**. Well Instead of putting mapper code in controller you should move it to Service as Controller shouldn't hold any such code.

That way problem would be fixed. Mapper can be placed here but that will be called bad approach.

At service layer it will work like a charm. Just do the following.

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface productMapper {...}
```

And in service class do the autowiring

```
@Autowired
private   productMapper productMapper;
```

You are done.

Comment: @Mapper at controller layer is a security hole, am I right with that assumption?

Comment: Well that cant be justified @Ayman Arif. But we need to respect the framework else we will endup creating security loopholes.

Comment: Im trying to map a memberId (integer) to member (entity), but it fails, i read here in SO that i should use a service for get member (entity) using his memberid (integer). The method in my service is called findById(int memid), but, in my service that method returns a DTO, because im alredy calling the mapping there, so the mapper interface expects a Member no a MemberDTO. What i should do?

Comment: @darioxlz in mapstruct  there is a argument `expression="java(and_your_service_call_here)"`
try using that or please provide more clarity in your question.